# Apps located on WindowsApps folder won't open after I deleted the folders from one of the apps inside

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-store

I Followed this recommendation for the same problem and turned out very bad:

"Windows Voice Recorder Crashes Immediately After Opening" :
"It's tricky for non-advanced user, but, you have to take ownership of WindowsApps folder (inside Program Files folder) and after that, look for all Windows Sound Recorder  folders (I have 2 related) (inside WindowsApps) and manually delete those.

Once deleted, you can go to the Store and download Voice Recorder and install it. After that, you'll see Voice Recorder works just fine again."
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-voice-recorder-crashes-immediately-after/231bbd9a-8af5-47ea-8786-6803ed352d5a

After doing that, I can't open any of the app that I installed through microsoft store, and I cannot oven open microsoft store...

when i turn on the computer shows
win32bridge.server.exe the parameter is incorrect

when opening windows recovery shows
FileSystemError -2144926975

I have no restore point. I tried

sfc /SCANNOW
and
dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

I also tried resetting microsoft store.

with no success.

There has to be a way to fix it without formatting my computer. Clear the index that references those folders belonging to the voice recorder or something like that, but my background on windows is poor (i'm a programmer so I am willing to follow a complicated process). In this post:
[Microsoft Store and other apps such as Calc and Photos won't launch after Windows' update](https://superuser.com/questions/1291732/microsoft-store-and-other-apps-such-as-calc-and-photos-wont-launch-after-window)

I saw you could do this if you had the package name:
Remove-AppxPackage -Package "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1712.3351.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
but I was very dumb and I deleted the folders with no backup.

Thanks a lot for any help or clues on this.

Comment: You might be able to use the appropriate ISO as a source to reinstall the application, however, what you ran into is actually expected.  You might have to perform an inplace install in order to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To restore the original permissions on the WindowsApps folder,
run an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) and enter the command :

```
icacls "%ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps" /q /c /t /reset
```

If this doesn't help, see
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

The WindowsApps folder should not be modified, except by Windows
applications. It is one of the most heavily protected folders in
Windows 10, as it contains all the Windows UWP apps, to which
Microsoft zealously guards the access.

Comment: I used that yesterday from this post https://superuser.com/questions/1288014/reset-default-acls-for-c-program-files-windowsapps and indeed work. There are still some apps that work, but won't open from the start menu like ubuntu.  If I connect to ubuntu through visual studio it works. If right click on it a on start menu and open it as administrator, it says wrong parameter. I have seen several post saying the wrong parameter thing is due to cortana but not in my case. Do you have any clues on the "incorrect parameter"?

Comment: Start a new post for the "incorrect parameter" problem, with more details about which apps give this error and which don't, and add a link to here for background info. Drop me a note when you do and I'll have a look.